# jquery check minimum characters and send form

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I have this script and this work fine to check minimum characters. But if the check is OK, I want send the form to update page. This script non send action post.

```
<form method="POST" id="myform" action="confirm.php">
<label for="field">Required, minimum length 3: </label>
<input type="text" class="left" id="field" name="field">
<br/>
<input type="submit" value="Validate!">
</form>

<script>
jQuery.validator.setDefaults({
  debug: true,
  success: "valid"
});
$( "#myform" ).validate({
  rules: {
    field: {
      required: true,
      minlength: 3
    }
  }
});
</script>
```

How do I fix it?

Comment: Have you tried reading jQuery's Ajax docs? http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

Comment: Remove `debug: true`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> This script non send action post.

It's not sending anything because you've set the `debug` option to `true`.

```
jQuery.validator.setDefaults({
    debug: true,  // <- BLOCKS form submit for testing purposes
    ....
```

See the docs:  [jqueryvalidation.org/validate/#debug](https://jqueryvalidation.org/validate/#debug)

> If true, the **form is not submitted** and certain errors are displayed on the console...